# Check whether an item in an array contains a 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im writing a simple statement which should check whether values in an array contain a 7.

I had the following in mind:

```
def checkforseven(an_array)
  newArray = []
   an_array.each do |num|
   if num.include?(7)
    newArray << num         
   end
  end
 newArray
end



array = [1,2,14,27]
exclaim(array)
```

But this not seem to work... Am getting a "nomethod error"

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for 1:Fixnum
```

Any thoughts on how I can solve this?

Comment: You need to use `include`on an `array`,not on its elements

Comment: Thanks @Pavan, any clue on how to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0):

> NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for 1:Fixnum

As i said,the `include` should be used with an `array`.Currently you are iterating `an_array` and using `include` on its elements,which is wrong.

Try this

```
def checkforseven(an_array)
  newArray = []
   if an_array.include?(7)
    newArray << an_array      
   end
 newArray
end
```

Comment: When I enter this on rubyfiddle with an array containing a 7 i get an empty return....

Comment: @user3706202 can you post the array which you entered?